# using ls with grep to zip selection of files

Tags: bash, grep, zip, pipe, ls

I'm trying to make my process at work more efficient by using bash.

I have these files 
20201.csv 20202.csv 20203.csv 20191.csv 20192.csv

with

```
ls | grep '2020*'
```

I'm extracting the files that start with 2020. 
I'm fighting with the syntax how to get the files in this smaller list to zip.

I have tried:

```
ls | grep '2020*' | zip archive.zip
ls | zip archive.zip grep '2020*'
```

I have tried writing to variable and I have read the Man / --help of zip and grep. 
I have visited about 20 different websites and stack pages.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231239/how-to-redirect-output-of-a-program-to-a-zip-file
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231239/how-to-redirect-output-of-a-program-to-a-zip-file
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-command-in-linux-with-examples/
and many more.

Could someone please help me understand the code? 
Where am I missing or where am I making the wrong assumption?

Many thanks.

Comment: Based on Glenns answer, this is the information I missed, no need to grep because it can be done natively in bash: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: The answer is in the link below: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777049/how-do-i-zip-up-multiple-files-on-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
zip archive.zip 2020*
```

is all you need.

While bash is parsing this line for execution, it will expand the file pattern *before* it launches `zip`.

An important thing to note about the difference between regular expressions:

- the regular expression `2020*` matches, anywhere in the string, "202" followed by *zero or more "0"*

  - the string "202" is matched by the regular expression `2020*`
  - the string "120201" is matched by the regular expression `2020*`
- the glob pattern `2020*` matches, starting at the beginning, "2020" followed by *zero or more of any character*

  - the file "202" is **not** matched by the glob pattern `2020*`
  - the file "120201" is  **not** matched by the glob pattern `2020*`